# Tool to rename folders and sub folder using a notepad file

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, directory

I was wondering if there is any tool that renames folder really quickly, using a note pad file,

For example, I made a tool that downloads nearly 1000+ folders, sub-folders and so on from a SharePoint document library site, and at the same time it logs name of folder with the number assigned to the folder, just to let you know the only reason I am doing this is because the directory path gets too long if i give folders the name they should have, and i cant download them.

Note: In note pad file it contains Name of Folder and Number that its assigned to.

and if there is any tutorial that can help me making this API, would be wonderful.

Cheers

Comment: What is a "notepad file"? Do you mean a text file?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, try the super-user site instead.

Comment: Using .NET, I don't think this is going to be a huge job.

Comment: @ Ranhiru, if you can provide me a tutorial link for something related then i will be able to make another API i guess please :)

Comment: @ColinE: if this is a programming question or not depends on the given answers. So I won't clos this early.

Comment: How is this name and number assigned in terms of sharepoint? Name = Doc library name and No = Doc Library URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if there is any software that reads from Notepad file and rename folders accordingly however, this freeware in given link might help you to achieve what you want,

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Comment: I already looked at this, but its not something I really looking for at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I do this when I have many file to rename individually, not using wildcart. (Like changing user file from family name to nick name, etc ... )

- dir /b > t.txt
- for /F %i in (t.txt) ren %i %i > t.bat
- notepad t.bat ( here you can use your preferred editor, some have great macro )
  ... (edit the file then save)
- t.bat
- del t.txt
- del t.bat

Answer (score 0):

So you have a file containing lines, where each line represents a folder name, and you have rules how to do some folder renaming for each of that lines?

You can use any programming language you like for that, for such a task I would personally use the windows command shell, along the lines of

```
`for /F %i in (textfilename.txt) do ren ...<renaming command here>`
```

Comment: I will probably be going to use C# Sir, Cheers :)